# Manipulação de Data em PHP

Tags: php

Boa tarde a todos.

Agradeceria de uma idéia para resolver meu problema:

Meus campos datainicio e datatermino estão sendo enviados ao BD utilizando esta preg_replace:

```
   public function getDatainicio()
   {  

   return $this->datainicio;

    }
   public function setDatainicio($datainicio)
 {   
 $datainicio= preg_replace("/\D+/", "", $datainicio); 
$this->datainicio = $datainicio;
 }

 public function getDatatermino()
 {     
  return $this->datatermino;
  }
 public function setDatatermino($datatermino)
 {   
$datatermino= preg_replace("/\D+/", "", $datatermino); 
$this->datatermino = $datatermino;
  }
```

Estou conseguindo inserir sem prolemas. Mas quando eu preciso criar o formulário de alteração eu estou retornando os dados do BD recebo desta forma:

["datainicio"]=> string(8) "20180921" ["datatermino"]=> string(8) "20180923"
Preciso converter para o padrão brasileiro e exibir no html e depois converter novamente se o usuário quiser alterar a data e enviar ao BD novamente com a data que ele aceita.

Já tentei alterar diretamente no HTML utilizando javascript mas não consegui resultado acho que é porque ele teria que receber no formato do BD 2018-09-21 e não 20180921.

Porque isto está acontecendo e qual o melhor método para resolver?

Este é meu html:

```
  <?php ini_set('display_errors', 1);?>
  <?php error_reporting(E_ALL);?>
 <?php require_once 'conecta.php' ?>
 <?php require_once 'cabecalho.php' ?>
 <?php require_once 'banco-curso.php' ?>
 <?php require_once 'banco-fornecedor.php' ?>
  <?php require_once 'curso.php' ?>
 <?php require_once 'fornecedor.php' ?>

 <?php
 $curso = new Curso();
 $curso->setFornecedor(new Fornecedor());
 if (array_key_exists('id', $_GET)) {
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $curso = buscaCurso($conexao, $id);
 }
 ?>

 <?php $fornecedores = listaFornecedores($conexao); ?>

 <?php
 $ehAlteracao = false;
 $action = "adiciona-curso.php";
 if (array_key_exists("id", $_GET)) {
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $curso = buscaCurso($conexao, $id);
 $ehAlteracao = true;
 $action = "altera-curso.php";
  }
  ?>
    <div class="container">
     <center><h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal"> <?=$ehAlteracao ? 
   "Alterar" :  "Cadastrar " ?>
     o Curso</h1><form action="<?=$action ?>"  method="post" ></center>
      <div class="form-group">

  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$curso->getId() ?>" />

  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <label for="inputEmail4">Nome do Curso</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" 
   placeholder="nome do curso" required 
  value="<?=$curso->getNome() ?>">
   </div>

 <div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label for="inputDataInicio">Data Inicio</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datainicio" name="datainicio"
  value="<?=$curso->getDatainicio() ?>"   required>

</div>  

   <div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label for="inputDataTermino">Data Término</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datatermino" 
    name="datatermino" 
  value= "<?=$curso->getDatatermino()?>" required>

</div>


   <div class="form-group col-md-8">
  <label for="professor">Professor</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="professor" name="professor" 
     placeholder="professor" required 
  value="<?=$curso->getProfessor() ?>">
 </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-8">
  <label for="local">Local do Curso</label>
  <select name="fornecedor_id" class="form-control">
  <option selected>Escolher...</option>
      <?php foreach($fornecedores as $fornecedor)  :?>
 <?php
     $essaEhAfornecedor = $curso->getfornecedor()->getId()
     == $fornecedor->getId();
     $selecao = $essaEhAfornecedor ? "selected='selected'" : "";
 ?>
    <option value="<?=$fornecedor->getId() ?>" <?=$selecao ?> >
        <?=$fornecedor->getCidade() ?>
    </option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
 </select>
 </div>
 <br>
<center><button type="submit" name="submit" id="registrar"
   class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!checked">CADASTRAR</button> 
  </center>

 </div>
```

**Este é meu banco nas funções altera e busca**

```
 function buscaCurso($conexao, $id) {
  $query = "select c.*, f.cidade as fornecedor_cidade from cursos c
  inner join fornecedores f on(c.fornecedor_id = f.id)
  where c.id = {$id}"; 

   $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
   $array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);        
   $curso = new curso();
   $curso->setId( $array['id'] );
   $curso->setNome( $array['nome'] );
    $curso->setFornecedor( new Fornecedor() );
    $curso->getFornecedor()->setId( $array['fornecedor_id'] );
    $curso->getFornecedor()->setCidade( $array['fornecedor_cidade'] );
    $curso->setDatainicio( $array['datainicio'] );
    $curso->setDatatermino( $array['datatermino'] );
    $curso->setProfessor( $array['professor'] );
    var_dump($curso); exit; 

    return $curso;


        }
```

Comment: Qual banco você está usando? Mysql, oracle, ...

Comment: Estou usando Mysql

Comment: O campo da data no banco é tipo data mesmo?

Comment: isso mesmo Adventistaam é data

Comment: já experimentou usar a função [DATE_FORMAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) do mysql? Exem. `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(campoData, '%d/%m/%Y' FROM suaTabela)` para recuperar a data no formato brasileiro